# Wazuh Manager Logging Issue

Tags: slack, wazuh

is it possible to stop wazuh logging its own manager but still logs the agents insted? I've been lookin for this for hours but still can't managed somehow.

I've configured a Slack integration to my Wazuh with Level 6 Minimum, but its spamming with Wazuh-Manager's alerts. I wanted to stop the Manager Log but don't want to stop the Agent Logs.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is identify the ones you want to delete and create a custom rule that deletes them for the manager's agent.

To delete an alert, you must set a custom rule for the alert you want to delete and set its level to 0.

For example:

```
 <rule id="100003" level="0">
    <if_sid>12345</if_sid>
    <description>Rule suppression</description>
 </rule>
```

To create a [rule](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/ruleset/ruleset-xml-syntax/rules.html).

To create a [custom rule](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/ruleset/custom.html).

To filter by the manager agent, you can use the [hostname tag](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/ruleset/ruleset-xml-syntax/rules.html#hostname).